# Pivoting rows to columns depending on data from another table

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables `VisitorsPerDay` and `Languages` as follows:

**Languages** table

```
|         Code        |       Alias      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          EN         |      English     |
|          AR         |      Arabic      |
|          FR         |      French      |
|          JP         |     Japanese     |
```

**VisitorsPerDay** table

```
|         Date        |  VisitorLanguage |    Count    |  
|---------------------|------------------|-------------|
|       10/1/2019     |        EN        |      20     |
|       10/1/2019     |        EN        |      10     |
|       10/1/2019     |        AR        |      5      |
|       15/1/2019     |        FR        |      1      |
```

What the result should be is aggregated data for each day and two columns for each language in the languages table dynamically in which if a new language has been added there will be no need to edit the stored procedure

```
|         Date        |    TotalVisits   |  En Visits  |  En AVG Visit %  |
|---------------------|------------------|-------------|------------------|
|       10/1/2019     |        35        |      30     |       85%        |
|       15/1/2019     |        1         |      0      |        0%        |
```

What I have done is created a dynamic query and a cursor that loop over the languages and generate the require SQL statements for each language and append it to the dynamic query

What I want to know is there a better way to get the result set or is a dynamic query OK?

Comment: Define better? Does it do the job you want it to do in a timely fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Dynamic SQL`, the query will be ugly and not easy to maintain

```
declare @sql    nvarchar(max)

select  @sql    = isnull(@sql + ',', 'SELECT [Date], TotalVisits = sum([Count]),' + char(13))
        + 'SUM(CASE WHEN VisitorLanguage = ''' + Code + ''' THEN [Count] END) AS [' + Code + ' Visits],'+ char(13)
        + 'SUM(CASE WHEN VisitorLanguage = ''' + Code + ''' THEN [Count] END) * 100 / SUM([Count]) AS [' + Code + ' AVG Visits %]'+ char(13)
from    Languages

select  @sql    = @sql + 'FROM VisitorsPerDay GROUP BY [Date]'

--  print out the dynmamic query
print   @sql
exec    sp_executesql @sql
```